# Delphi logging with multiple sinks and delayed classification?

Tags: delphi, logging

Imagine i want to parse a binary blob of data. If all comes okay, then all the logs are INFO, and user by default does not even see them. If there is an error, then user is presented with error and can view the log to see exact reason (i don't like programs that just say "file is invaid. for some reason. you do not want to know it" )

Probably most log libraries are aimed at quickly loading, classifying and keeping many many log lines per second. *which by itself is questionable, as there is no comfort lazy evaluation and closures in Delphi. Envy Scala :-)*

However that need every line be pre-сlassified.

Imagine this hypothetical flow:

- 1. Got object FOO [ok]

     - 1.1. found property BAR  [ok]

       - 1.1.1. parsed data for BAR [ok]
     - 1.2 found property BAZ [ok]

       - 1.2.1 successfully parsed data for BAR [ok]
       - 1.2.2 matching data: checked dependancy between BAR and BAZ [fail]
         ...

So, what can be desired features?

1) Nested logging (indenting, subordination) is desired then.
Something like highlighted in TraceTool - see **TraceNode.Send Method** at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/tracetool.aspx#premain0

2) The 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1 lines are sent as they happen in a info sink (TMemo, OutputDebugString, EventLog and so one), so user can see and report at least which steps are complete before error.

3) 1, 1.2, 1.2.2 are retroactively marked as error (or warning, or whatever) inheriting from most specific line. Obviously, warning superseeds info, error superseeds warning and info, etc/

4) 1 + 1.2 + 1.2.2 can be easily combined like with **LogMessage('1.2.2').FullText** to be shown to user or converted to Exception, to carry the full story to human.

4.1) Optionally, with relevant setup, it would not only be converted to Exception, but the latter even would be auto-raised. This probably would require some kind of context with supplied exception class or supplied exception constructing callback.

5) Multisink: info can be just appended into collapsible panel with TMemo on main form or currently active form. The error state could open such panel additionally or prompt user to do it. At the same time some file or network server could for example receive warning and error grade messages and not receive info grade ones.

6) extra associated data might be nice too. Say, if to render it with TreeView rather than TMemo, then it could have "1.1.1. parsed data for BAR [ok]" item, with mouse tooltip like "Foo's dimensions are told to be 2x4x3.2 metres"

- Being free library is nice, especially free with sources. Sometimes track and fix the bug relying solely on DCUs is much harder.
- Non-requiring extra executable. it could offer extra more advanced viewer, but should not be required for just any functionality.
- Not being stalled/abandoned.
- ability to work and show at least something before GUI is initialized would be nice too. Class constructors are cool, yet are executed as part of unit visualization, when VCL is not booted yet. If any assertion/exception is thrown from there, user would only see Runtime error 217, with all the detail lost. At least OutputDebugStreen can be used, if nothing more...

Stack tracing is not required, if needed i can do it and add with Jedi CodeLib. But it is rarely needed.

External configuration is not required. It might be good for big application to reconfigure on the fly, but to me simplicity is much more important and configuration in code, by calling constructors or such, is what really matters. Extra XML file, like for Log4J, would only make things more fragile and complex.

I glanced few mentioned here libraries.

- TraceTool has a great presentation, link is above. Yet it has no info grade, only 3 predefined grades (Debug/Error/Warning) and nothing more, but maybe Debug would suit for Info replacement... Seems like black box, only saving data into its own file, and using external tool to view it, not giving stream of events back to me. But their messages nesting and call chaining seems cool. Cools is also attaching objects/collection to messages.
- Log4D and Log4Delphi seems to be in a stasis, with last releases of 2007 and 2009, last targeted version Delphi 7. Lack documentation (probably okay for log4j guy, but not for me :- ) Log4Delphi even had test folder - but those test do not compile in Delphi XE2-Upd1. Pity: In another thread here Log4delphi been hailed for how simple is to create custom log appender (sink)...

  - *BTW, the very fact that the only LOG4J was forked into two independent Delphi ports leaves the question of which is better and that both lack something, if they had to remain in split.*
- mORMot part is hardly separated from the rest library. Demo application required UAC escalation for use its embedded SQLite3 engine and is frozen (no window opened, yet the process never exits normally) if refused Admin grants. Another demo just started infinite stream of AV exceptions, trying to unwind the stack. So is probably not ready yet for last Delphi. Though its list of message grades is excessive, maybe even a bit too many.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like Cronon would be nice: [Chronon 2.0: Pushing the Boundaries of Logging](http://java.dzone.com/articles/chronon-20-pushing-boundaries), introducing a groundbreaking technology called 'Post Execution Logging'.

Comment: log4d code has been updated 6 months ago (see http://log4d.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/log4d/)

Comment: There's a lot of requirements there, but I recommend a good look at Codesite. It has a lot of the hierarchical requirement you have, and can send whole objects of information to logs. And jump around the data quickly. I have found it really good to debug a word processor that might output a hundred thousand debug lines for each character pressed (100 pages of pagination). With alternative colouring and thread filtering, and all sorts, it may be sufficient for you.

Comment: A "binary blob"?  I ought to report you to the Department of Redundancy Department for that...

Comment: @mj2008, I can't find any notes about source code of CodeSite.

Comment: @LU You'd have to talk to Raize, but I think you might be able to have source to the bit that goes in your app, but not the rest. But it isn't abandoned!

Comment: @mjn quite possibly SVN saw some action. But 6 months ago is quite a long ago. At least quite before Delph XE2 released. And that is SVN work in progress, not stable releases for download. I can try snapshots of tools, that i understand well and can fix and maybe even submit patches. Log4D is not in this list, i'd prefer to get experience with stable release first. BTW, the fact that for so long there were no stable releases implies that the community and the projects are dying. Then maybe it just does not worth to get dependant on it.

Comment: @mj2008 for what i read in other topics, Codesite depends upon extra executable, runned as system service/daemon. There is no way to make self-contained application. So, this rules it out.

Comment: @Mason WheelerL i do not like this joke. Looking at http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict we can see _Something blunt and round; a small drop or lump of something viscid or thick; a drop; a bubble; a blister. [1913 Webster]_
When computer-related jargonizm replaces regular life language, it is sad :-/

Comment: @mjn _When you are done executing, you can open the recording in Chronon and add logging_
Even if it was not for JVM, that is not what i need :-) Not storing a laaaaarge stream of states for post-execution analyzis, thour interesting per se, but during execution JIT actions :-)

Interesting solution - not to problem of mine :-)

Comment: Your comments about mORMot are unfair and should be updated to the current state of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

mORMot is stable, even with latest XE2 version of Delphi.

What you tried starting were the regression tests. Among its 6,000,000 tests, it includes the HTTP/1.1 Client-Server part of the ORM. Without the Admin rights, the *http.sys* Server is not able to register the URI, so you got errors. Which makes perfectly sense. It's a Vista/Seven restriction, not a mORMot restriction.

*The logging part can be used completely separated from the ORM part*. Logging is implemented in `SynCommons.pas` (and `SynLZ.pas` for the fast compression algorithm used for archival and .map embedding). I use the `TSynLog` class without any problem to log existing applications (even Delphi 5 and Delphi 6 applications), existing for years. The SQLite3 / ORM classes are implemented in other units.

It supports the nesting of events, with auto-leave feature, just as you expect. That is you can write:

```
procedure TMyClass.MyMethod(const Params: integer);
begin
  TSynLog.Enter;
  // .... my method code
end;
```

And adding this `TSynLog.Enter` will be logged with indentation corresponding to the recursive level. IMHO this may meet your requirements. It will declare an `ISynLog` interface on the stack, which will be freed by Delphi at the "`end;`" code line, so it will implement an *Auto-Leave* feature. And the exact unit name, method name and source code line number will be written into the log (as `MyUnit.TMyClass.MyMethod (123)`), if you generated a .map file at compilation (which may be compressed and appended to the .exe so that your customers logs will contain the source line numbers). You have methods at the `ISynLog` interface level to add some custom logging, including parameters and custom state (you can log objects properties as JSON if you need to, or write your custom logging data).

The exact timing of each methods are tracked, so you are able to profile your application from the data supplied by your customer.

If you think the logs are too much verbose, you have several levels of logging, to be customized on the client side. See the [blog articles](http://blog.synopse.info/?q=tsynlog) and the corresponding part of the [framework documentation](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Downloads) (in the *SynCommons* part). You've for instance "Fail" events and some custom kind of events. And it is totally VCL-independent, so you can use it without GUI or before any GUI is started.

You have at hand a log viewer, which allow client-side profiling and nested Enter/Leave view (if you click on the "Leave" line, you'll go back to the corresponding "Enter", e.g.):

[image: Log Viewer]

If this log viewer is not enough, you have its source code to make it fulfill your requirements, and all the needed classes to parse and process the .log file on your own, if you wish. Logs are textual by default, but can be compressed into binary on request, to save disk space (the log viewer is able to read those compressed binary files). Stack tracing and exception interception are both implemented, and can be activated on request.

You could easily add a numeration like "1.2.1" to the logs, if you wish to. You've got the whole source code of the logging unit. Feel free to ask any question [in our forum](http://synopse.info).

Comment: _> Without the Admin rights, ... you got errors._
I do not, At least on this Win7 x64 box. The process just keeps hanging in the Task Manager with no window opened.

Comment: _>if you generated a .map file_

Generally i do JDBG embedding instead. AFAIR your code is said to depend upon JCL for stack trace, so it should use it, but nowhere mentioned. But afterall that was exactly stack unwinding, that threw me infinite errors stream. Maybe i'd better disable stack trace at all.

Comment: I almost can feel Your passion towards your software. The whole second part you re-tell already told stories from blog, site and other s.o. question. That should be very boring task and you seems to be very fond of your projects.

Yet it mostly seems like nice bonuses to me, not the features a feel i need right now. External viewer ? Well, good, maybe, if some heavy logging would be needed some day and if the application would grow 100 times from what is planned. BTW, did not tried it in practical workload, but on the screenshot TraceTools viewer seems to be more flexible :P

Comment: Profiler ? same here. Nice bonus that i maybe once would need.

_You've got the whole source code_ - same for other libre projects i mentioned. Including one more now-dead Nexus Overseer. But at this point i doubt if making yet another ad hoc quazi-logger would not be faster, than investigating and after that forking some complex project with lots of clever code, that has to be grasped.

Comment: when runned fro Delphi IDE with last-release JCL installed, 
_--- 
Debugger Exception Notification
 --- 
Project LoggingTest.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x760cd09c: read of address 0x77ba129f'. _  Adresses are changed, yet it always happens near "if ((st>max_stack) or (st<min_stack)) and" line. After dozen of "run on" i gave up on this and considered infinite loop. If run w/o IDE, project just dies living text log file, without showing window even for ea second. Perhaps really infinite loop and stack overflow.

Comment: @Arioch The library do not depend on JCL at all - I don't know why you speak about JCL here. On which IDE did you try it? Did you use the latest 1.15 version? It compiled and worked with Delphi 5,6,7,2007,2010 and XE2, and run on 32 or 64 bit PCs using XP, Vista, or Seven. As I wrote, if you don't need stack trace, you can disable it. Our unit do not embedd the .map file, but a compressed .mab version, which is much more compact than JDBG. TraceTools has a diverse architecture and features, and is much more heavy. In all cases, thanks for taking your time looking this and reading my answer.

Comment: @Arioch About custom exception creation, I think you're mixing two features: unit testing and logging. Both are usually bounded, but are diverse in nature. For instance, in our same SynCommons.pas unit, you have some unit-testing classes which can easily log all testing results, and raise exceptions on failure. And if you ask for runtime exceptions on failure, it should be part of the binary parsing routine, and not unit tests or logging, IMHO. You should better architecture your software over those three levels: parser, logger, automated testing (the later fits very well any parsing routine).

Comment: Yes, that's the point. You see logging as solely debugging method. Not the method to communicate something to user. And most frameworks share this view. That's why they are aimed at "store as much and as fast as possible" goal.  But i am talking of logging as a message bus to user as well, not mere debug tools, hidden from regular user.

Comment: @Arioach So it is not logging, but IPC messaging. You are searching in the wrong area of tools, and may ask another question more focused on  this requirement. Take a look over SOA and how it may help you.

Comment: IPC ? u mean INTER-processes ? No, single process and single user.
Of course, in theory, we may consider user the blackbox process, but it is too much :-)

Logging, just like any free text communication, would be doubtful thing for IPC. Excluding console applications perhaps. But this is not IPC at all. Program-to-user, just so.

Comment: 6,000,000 tests? Care to share how you achieved this number?:) I would gladly read article about this on your site.

Comment: Here test = check. And currently we reached 18,000,000 checks in 30 seconds. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/11/20/BeDelphi-2014-Slides. BTW you have now remote logging if needed, even from mobiles or HTML,5 apps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Log4D supports *nested diagnostic contexts* in the **TLogNDC** class, they can be used to group together all steps which are related to one compound action (instead of a 'session' based grouping of log events). Multi-Sinks are called Appenders in log4d and log4delphi so you could write a TLogMemoAppender with around twentyfive lines of code, and use it at the same time as a ODSAppender, a RollingFileAppender, or a SocketAppender, configurable at run time (no external config file required).

Comment: are there some demos (compilable in xe2u1) about using multiple appenders for same messages, and configuring in runtime for having different appenders sets for different messages ? yes, exception auto-creation can be made as custom appender as well. _BTW, articles on logging for Java suggest that log4j eventually came to dead end, and developing team disbanded. Only mantainers and patches can be made but no further enhancement._

Comment: _Since log4d and log4delphi (and why are they separate??? what are the drawbacks that justify this split?) are modeled after log4j this again casts doubt upon their future. If i already had experience with it, then who would care about develpment until it completely breakes. But i am thinking of making new relative, not keeping olds one :-)_

Oh, my... i feel like in twitter here :-(